# Do you need cheesecloth to wrap around a dry aged beef?

Tags: beef, dry-aging

If so, how many layers do I need to wrap them and how does it work?

I read from another article, that cheesecloth allows air to pass through while also preventing excessive dehydration since home refrigerators are less humid. But in my case, I control the humidity level at 80%-85% inside the cooler. Do I still need to wrap my beef with cheesecloth even though the environment is controlled?

Comment: Also I read from other article, it said that cheesecloth allow air to pass through while also preventing excessive dehydration hence home refrigerators are less humid. But in my case, I control humidity level at 80%-85% inside the cooler. Do I still need to wraps my beef with cheesecloth eventhough the environment is controls.

Answer (score 3):

Cheesecloth is not 'required' for dry aging, but it is helpful. You can substitute a wrapping of paper towels. You want something to absorb the moisture that will be released during the aging process. For a good primer on home dry aging see [Alton Brown's "Porterhouse Rules"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4aI_O8kcN8)